# What actually happens when Windows installs something? Why not run the executable standalone?

Tags: windows, installation, registry, executable

I'm used to coding in Java and if I ever need to share my work I send a plain'n'simple JAR. So why is installation usually a complicated seeming process in Windows?

Why is it that some programs run as standalone and others install? Why does Firefox have both an installation and a portable version, what's the difference?

Comment: Windows is completely not involved with installers.  They just do whatever they need to do to make the program they install work.  Which is rarely much beyond copying the files, add a Start menu entry, creating a shortcut on the desktop and registering the uninstaller.  Simple user conveniences.  Firefox does more since it also needs another program to download updates.  Etcetera.  It is not complicated, merely obscure.  Otherwise the kind of obscurity that programs like InstallShield make a living of.

Comment: Even if the code is all in a .jar file it's not uncommon to distribute an installer.  Such an installer would typically check to see if the Java runtime is present and install it if necessary, as well as some of the things Hans mentioned.  If the program works with documents, the installer might also register the document extension so the user can double-click a document to launch the application.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you have designed and planned your deployment: Let us say you have planned to have all your application dependencies in the same folder, and you have no dependencies on external assemblies, then you can develop your app and all its dependencies and put them in same folder. Now you can distrbute same folder, assuming you do not want to check for any pre-condition for running your app, now your app does not really require any installer. Also make sure your app does not depend on any registry entries etc.

However most apps can not be like that, they would like to make sure the system is right, it has right version of windows, right dependencies are pre installed, and there are certain locations only where the app needs to be installed and only there it can work. Or the application needs to write to registry and read from it etc. All such conditions and validations are possible with installer - the installer enables you to define how yo want your pre-checks, post checks, registrations etc happen. The installer is just a tool that enables the way application has to be deplyed on the machine and ensure the application is installed on a machine and in conditions designed for application to run, thus the need for installer. IF your Java program does need to do the same things, then you would have to develop installer for your java program as well